# Not sure I'm using useFitTest package properly

Tags: javascript, callback

I am using this package useFitText(https://www.npmjs.com/package/use-fit-text) to resize fonts on the fly. I want to call a hook when it has finished resizing

```
const {ref, fontSize) = useFitText({
  onFinish: () => {
    console.log('fontSize', fontSize);
    setFinalFontSiz(fontSize)
  }
});
```

When I don't have the onFinish callback fontSize will change, when I do, it will not change.

Am I doing this wrong, or is it a bug in the package possibly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the documentation try this:

```
const {ref, fontSize} = useFitText({
  onFinish: (finalSize) => {
    console.log('fontSize', finalSize);
    setFinalFontSiz(finalSize);
  }
});
```

You had a syntax error in your destructuring, should be `const {ref, fontSize}` as above. The `finalSize` is passed to the `onFinish` callback as a parameter which represents the final font size used.

Comment: hmm, this is in a typeScript file, I'm getting a warning that finalSize is declared but never used

Comment: are you using the code from above? it's definitely being used so that's weird

Comment: Sorry, my bad. Unfortunately, I'm still having the original issue though :(